# Keeping the x axis interval fixed highstock

Tags: php, highcharts

Could you really help with the following:Can we have options/controls for handling the range selector entries.
like,
for 48 hour we need to show data in every hour interval,  for 7days we need to show dta in every hour interval,  for 1 month we need to show data in days interval,  for  3 month we need to show data in days interval,  for  6 months  - every day,  for 1 year -  then interval must be week,   for All   - week.

this is my code ,

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=large-dataset.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // Create the chart
        jQuery('#highchart').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                alignTicks: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            exporting: { enabled: false },

            rangeSelector: {

                buttons: [{
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 2,
                        text: '48h'
                    }, {
                        type: 'day',
                        count: 7,
                        text: '7d'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 3,
                        text: '3m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'month',
                        count: 6,
                        text: '6m'
                    }, {
                        type: 'year',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1y'
                    }, {
                        type: 'all',
                        text: 'All'
                    }],
                selected: 3
            },

            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            series: [{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Number',
                    data: data,
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1),
                    pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,

                    dataGrouping: {
                        enabled: true,
                        units: [ [
                                'hour',
                                [1]
                            ], [
                                'day',
                                [1]
                            ], [
                                'week',
                                [1]
                            ],[
                                'year',
                                null
                            ]]

                    }
                }]

        },
```

Currently i have got the output correct exept for 1month and 1 year ,

for 1 month i got interval as hour instead of day and for 1 year for lower resolution monitor i got it as week and larger resolution monitor as day .

What i need exectly is ,

48h's x-axis = every hour as a point

7d's x-axis = every hour

1m's x-axis = every day

3m's x-axis = every day

6m'a x-axis = every day

1y's x-axis = every week

All's x-axis = every week

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

For preparing custom tick positions, you should use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner).

Comment: But my X axis     type: 'datetime', and I have Range selector  buttons 48h,7day,1 month etc.Is there any JSFiddle with Type datetime.Please excuse me for my lack of expertise.@sebastian-bochan